# Yii2 Codeception No tests executed

Tags: php, yii2, codeception, yii2-basic-app

I've tried setting up Codeception within a project using the Yii2 basic template following this [guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/README.md#testing)

Within my project folder I have 3 unit tests under
\tests\unit. Here's one of them

```html
<?php
namespace tests\models;
use app\models\User;

class UserTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    public function testFindUserById()
    {
        expect_that($user = User::findIdentity(100));
        expect($user->username)->equals('admin');

        expect_not(User::findIdentity(999));
    }

    public function testFindUserByAccessToken()
    {
        expect_that($user = User::findIdentityByAccessToken('100-token'));
        expect($user->username)->equals('admin');

        expect_not(User::findIdentityByAccessToken('non-existing'));        
    }

    public function testFindUserByUsername()
    {
        expect_that($user = User::findByUsername('admin'));
        expect_not(User::findByUsername('not-admin'));
    }

    /**
     * @depends testFindUserByUsername
     */
    public function testValidateUser($user)
    {
        $user = User::findByUsername('admin');
        expect_that($user->validateAuthKey('test100key'));
        expect_not($user->validateAuthKey('test102key'));

        expect_that($user->validatePassword('admin'));
        expect_not($user->validatePassword('123456'));        
    }

}
```

After following the guide up till step 7 everything worked exactly as described in the guide but once I try running my tests, this is what I get

```html
codecept run
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.3.6
Powered by PHPUnit 5.7.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

[1mAcceptance Tests (0) [22m---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[1mFunctional Tests (0) [22m---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[1mUnit Tests (0) [22m---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 520 ms, Memory: 12.25MB

[30;43mNo tests executed![0m
```

Comment: What is the name of the file containing these tests? It must end with Test.php

Comment: Well I didn't yet bother changing the template's filename. It's "LoginFormTest.php" so that shouldn't be the problem